# php_ibm_db2.dll on IIS 7.5 using PHP 5.3 error message

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, php5, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to use ibm_db2 extension to access iSeries DB2 database.

This is the testcode (taken from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php))

```
<?php
$database = 'ALI452BFAL'; //library
$user = 'STN452';
$password = '**********';
$hostname = 'myserverip';
$port = 50000;

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    print "ok";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo db2_conn_error() . '<br>' . db2_conn_errormsg();
}
?>
```

I have installed a very basic package containing the db2 driver and added this as an extension.
 *(IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC, CLI, and .NET.msi)*

This is my result:

> 08001 [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N A communication error has been
>   detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication
>   API being used: "SOCKETS". Location where the error was detected:
>   "10.10.0.120". Communication function detecting the error: "connect".
>   Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*". SQLSTATE=08001
>   SQLCODE=-30081

Anybody tried this before??

Comment: Are you connecting via a DB2 Connect gateway?  Or is 'myserverip' the IP address of the iSeries server?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to connect directly to the server so yes, myserverip is the iSeries Server ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port number you are using is incorrect – iSeries servers use port 446, not port 50000.

However, in order to use the *IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC, CLI and .Net* to access your iSeries server, you must have a license for the IBM product called [DB2 Connect](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2-connect-family/).

You do not need to use DB2 Connect, you can use the *[IBM i Access for Windows](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows.html)* product, which provides an ODBC driver to connect directly to your iSeries server.

Comment: Hi, I looked for the default port but couldn't find anything. So thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I don't know if we have a license for DB2 Connect. How can I check this? I know I could connect using ODBC but I would like to use a native driver for increased compatibility/functionality.

Comment: Nevermind Ian, I changed the port to 446 (+ the database, I gave a Library file) and now I get this error which confirms we are not licensed to use DB2 Connect...

`[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL8002N An attempt to connect to a host failed due to a missing DB2 Connect product or invalid license. SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-8002`

But do I need a client license or server license?